# how to wait the binding into angular directive attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive in angular that has an user-id as attribute.

```
<my-directive user-id="123"></my-directive>
```

I want to use it in my profile page, but i get that id in my controller after an http call. So i have tried to use it like that:

```
<my-directive user-id="user.id"></my-directive>
```

But It loads before the user.id gets the value so its undefined. I should wait until the binding is done.
I could watch user but like this it loads twice the directive.
I hope i explained myself

Comment: Can you show the directive code?

Comment: You could also use `ng-if` on the directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-if` to only render the directive when `user.id` is defined:

```
<my-directive user-id="user.id" ng-if="user.id >= 0"></my-directive>
```

Comment: Isn't there a better way? Then every time you use the directive, you'll have to think about the ng-if. Isn't there a flag provided by angular telling it to wait? The only solution I could come up with is to wrap the directive in another directive which does the ng-if for you, so the enduser of the directive won't have to think about the ng-if anymore...